# raid1 not assemble

Tags: 14.04, raid, mdadm

I have software raid and it is not assemble when I tried to assemble it. Below I am showing output of some commands.

**mdadm -A -s /dev/md1 /dev/sda /dev/sdb -f -v**

```
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md1, slot 0.
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdb to /dev/md1: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sda to /dev/md1: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md1: Invalid argument
mdadm: /dev/sda not identified in config file.
mdadm: /dev/sdb not identified in config file.
```

**mdadm -E /dev/sda**

```
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b4c9b859:2c9b90cb:c8e613ad:34747fee
           Name : naspro:1  (local to host naspro)
  Creation Time : Thu Oct  8 14:43:29 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766720 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e1d19cd8:56aac050:3f69b93e:ff47b608

    Update Time : Tue Jul 12 18:19:37 2016
       Checksum : fb9d3a29 - correct
         Events : 350


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

**mdadm -E /dev/sdb**

```
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : b4c9b859:2c9b90cb:c8e613ad:34747fee
           Name : naspro:1  (local to host naspro)
  Creation Time : Thu Oct  8 14:43:29 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906767024 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953383360 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906766720 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c4700b49:207fd67c:f47ca059:66a0731d

    Update Time : Tue Jul 12 18:19:37 2016
       Checksum : c7c619f3 - correct
         Events : 350


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

**mdadm --version**

```
mdadm - v3.2.5 - 18th May 2012
```

Please help to Solve My problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below command solved my problem.

```
mdadm --assemble --update=devicesize /dev/md1
```